# javascript function keeps refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a .net page, and I am using the bootstrap progress bara to display a value like such.

```
 <div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
progress    
</div>
```

Then, based on a predefined value (from database) we will set a value for progress bar, like so

```
function onload() {

        var value = 30; //assume later stage this value will come from database
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $("#progress-bar")
           .css("width", value + "%")
           .attr("aria-valuenow", value)
           .text(value + "%");
        }, 1000);
};

onload();
```

Then I want the user to be able to update the progress bar value. I have the input like such

```
 <div id="someDiv">
Update progress
</div>

 <br><br>

 <input id="someInput" type="text">
 <input type="button" value="Update" onClick="doStuff()">

<br>
```

Then the javascript to update the progress bar value is as such

```
  function doStuff() {
        var nameElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
        var theName = nameElement.value;
        var value = theName;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $("#progress-bar")
            .css("width", value + "%")
            .attr("aria-valuenow", value)
            .text(value + "%");
        }, 1000);
    }
```

But what is happening, once I hit the update button, the progress bar moves to 70%, then back to 30% then 70% etc. So it goes between the 2, so I am assuming the `<script>` keeps getting load again and again.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

> **CAUSE**

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function will call the callback function repeatedly until stopped.

Since you're calling [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) multiple times: in `onload()` and in `doStuff()` both are running concurrently and try to update the same progress bar, possibly with different values.

> **SOLUTION**

If you need to call the function just once, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead.

Otherwise you need to use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) to cancel previously defined action before calling [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for the second time.

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) returns interval ID which is required for [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) later. You need to store interval ID in a global variable.

> **DEMO**

```js
var interval = null;

function onload() {

  var value = 30; //assume later stage this value will come from database
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#progress-bar")
      .css("width", value + "%")
      .attr("aria-valuenow", value)
      .text(value + "%");
  }, 1000);
};


function doStuff() {
  var nameElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
  var theName = nameElement.value;
  var value = theName;

  // If interval is set, clear it
  if (interval !== null) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#progress-bar")
      .css("width", value + "%")
      .attr("aria-valuenow", value)
      .text(value + "%");
  }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  onload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="someDiv">
  Update progress
</div>

<br>
<br>
<input id="someInput" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Update" onClick="doStuff()">

<br>
<br>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
    progress
  </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTES**

I think you don't need `setTimout` or `setInterval` since there is no sense in updating the progress bar repeatedly or with a delay with the same value.

Comment: hey, would you have exampel on how use clearInternval in my code, I tried using it, but it didnt change the behaviour.

Comment: @test, added demo and some notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reload the page after a period of time, you can define meta data tag
Eg: Reload the page every 30 seconds

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```